# Vue js and cloned components

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a form that contain a list of v-select managed by Vue js, all select in my application is managed by this module and other input field are a sample html field.
when i clone the form with jquery I lose all action click in my select.
anyone has any idea on how to add with jquery the html cloned of v-select as a Vue component ?
The vue select is managed like this:

```
    init: function () {
    const node = $('.custom-vue-select');

    if (node) {
        node.each(function (index) {
            let id = index;
            App.components['customVueSelect_' + id] = new Vue({
                'el': this,
                'mixins': [App.customVueSelect.mixins]
            });
            App.lazy(this, function () {
                App.components['customVueSelect_' + id] && App.components['customVueSelect_' + id].reset();
            });
        });
    }

    }
```

Comment: Uhhh... why are you mixing jQuery and Vue? This is just setting yourself up for failure.

Comment: yes i agree , this is the only component managed by vue js and before migration of this compenent i need if there is some idea with jquery ?

Comment: How're you cloning the form? You might be better off reinstantiating the Vue components inside the form instead of copying them over.

Comment: like this: let $container= $('.container #content-' + $sectionType + "-" + $id).clone();

Comment: i will try to delete vue generated html and instantiating another one with jquery and see what is the result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is one solution with jquery : replace the DOM generated by Vue js and create another one like this:

```
        let vuSelect = $('.v-select');
        if (vuSelect) {
            let id = vuSelect.attr('id'),
                template = `
                        <v-select class="form-control custom-combobox"
                              id="${id}"
                              name="${id}">
                        </v-select>
                        `;
            vuSelect.replaceWith(template);
           new Vue({ el: '#components-select' });
        }
```